# BizTalk licensing, can standard edition have configuration database deployed remotely?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

So confusing about their license statement 'Single server solution/single message box', can the message box on another server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Standard Edition allows the use of a remote (2nd server) SQL Instance.

You are also permitted to Cluster the SQL Instance(s) used for BizTalk SE.

You may *not* Cluster the Master Secret Server and you *may* not have more than one BizTalk Host Computer.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding BizTalk licensing, "single server/single message box", means you will only have 1 BizTalk server having only 1 message box configured.

Keep in mind that the message box is "more or less" nothing more than an additional database in SQL server. You can put the BizTalk databases on a single SQL server instance, spread out over more than 1 instance or over more than 1 SQL logical server. It doesn't really matter. What you have to take care of, is to only have 1 BizTalk server running at all times for that specific environment and that that BizTalk server can only have 1 message box.

To be honest, having multiple message boxes for a single server could only do so much.
For more information regarding multiple message boxes, see the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296848(v=bts.10).aspx